How to fix frayed Magsafe 3 cable?
My Apple MagSafe 3 to USB-C cable frayed at the USB-C end, and doesn't charge. Should I just electrical tape it or get a new cable off Amazon? This is a school charger, and I don't wan to pay the ~$100 to get it replaced for a small fray.

Don’t mess with this for safety reasons. Embedded in the $49 cable is a small microprocessor with firmware that gets upgraded periodically for the cable to work.
Your cable’s armor was defeated and key connections broken, so please save that for trade in if you “repair it with Apple” or recycling.

Get a quality and inexpensive USB C charge cable if you can’t get the school or Apple to replace the MagSafe cord. If you have to pay, wait until you can be sure you won’t damage it before the equipment return date unless you depend on MagSafe to keep the Mac from being yanked to the ground. Then the cost of a cable is so much less than a damage repair on your Mac.
Anker has many high quality cables in the below $14 price point.

https://www.anker.com/collections/usb-c

Amazon can have some counterfeit products, but their return policy is decent. There are no third party MagSafe 3 currently, so if you need that, get it from Apple is my advice.

MagSafe 3 chargers have many electrical protection features, because power delivery can send  up to 140 watts over that cable, which can be dangerous.
If there is a short or overheating or any similar issue the charger will refuse to charge or at least charge more than 5 watts (USB). So it's likely that only the cable needs replacing.
You can also use a USB-C charging cable (one designed for charging) if you have one, you do not need to rely on only the MagSafe cable.
